# Libgdx: how to pick a color with a float value

Tags: java, colors, libgdx

I want to make a sort of a colorwheel where you enter a float value to get a certain color

Here is the code i currently have:

```
private Color Wheel(float WheelPos) {
    WheelPos = 255 - WheelPos;
    if(WheelPos < 85) {
        return new Color((255 - WheelPos * 3)/255, 0,(WheelPos * 3)/255,1);
    }
    if(WheelPos < 170) {
        WheelPos -= 85;
        return new Color(0, (WheelPos * 3)/255, (255 - WheelPos * 3)/255,1);
    }
    WheelPos -= 170;
    return new Color((WheelPos * 3)/255, (255 - WheelPos * 3)/255, 0,1);
}
```

the colors between the r,g,b colors look not colorfull at all 
How do i make these colors brighter?
[image]

Comment: Well... color has a method to make things brighter (either brighter or lighter or something). But I feel like your looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything to be bright, you can use your input value as the hue, and then calculate color from hue, saturation, and value (saturation and value both being at maximum).

Math taken from Android's Color class and simplified for full saturation/value:

```
//note, hue is on 0-360 scale.
public static Color hueToSaturatedColor(float hue) {
    float r,g,b;
    float Hprime = hue/60;
    float X = 1 - Math.abs(Hprime%2 - 1);
    if (Hprime<1){
        r = 1;
        g = X;
        b = 0;
    } else if (Hprime<2){
        r = X;
        g = 1;
        b = 0;
    } else if (Hprime<3){
        r = 0;
        g = 1;
        b = X;
    } else if (Hprime<4){
        r = 0;
        g = X;
        b = 1;
    } else if (Hprime<5){
        r = X;
        g = 0;
        b = 1;
    } else if (Hprime<6){
        r = 1;
        g = 0;
        b = X;
    } else {
        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 0;
    }

    return new Color(r, g, b, 1);
}
```